# Groupbox created in code doesn't dock correctly to parent TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, dock

In my `C# WinForm application` I have a `tableLayoutPanel` with only one row and two columns. The left column contains a TreeView, the right one another `tableLayoutPanel` which was set to `Dock: Fill` in the designer. I want to create several `GroupBoxes` programmatically that should use the full width of this second column also when the form is resized.

In the designer of Visual Studio it looks like this:

[image: Designer View of my tableLayout Panel]

But when the application runs, the GroupBoxes don't use the complete width and it looks like this:

[image: Dock: Fill is not used]

I'm using two methods to create the GroupBoxes (you can ignore the int values):

```
private void addDashboardRow(int i, int s)
{
     // Add one row to dashboardTableLayoutPanel
     sensorTableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;
     // Maybe this one is wrong, but SizeType.AutoSize doesn't work either
     sensorTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 75f));
     sensorTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(createSensorGroupbox(i, s));
}
```

```
private GroupBox createSensorGroupbox(int i, int sen)
{
     GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
     //g.Width = 500;          // I don't want fixed sizes, height of 75px is sufficient
     //g.Height = 75;
     g.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     g.Text = "Sensor " + sen.ToString();

     // just one label as example...
     Label temp = new Label();
     temp.Text = "Temperature: ";
     temp.Location = new Point(5, 20);
            
     Label tempVal = new Label();
     tempVal.Text = "°C";
     tempVal.Location = new Point(5, 50);
     tempVal.Name = "Sensor" + sen.ToString() + "_temp";

     //[... more labels]
     g.Controls.Add(temp);
     g.Controls.Add(tempVal);

     return g;
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. How can I fit the GroupBox into the complete width of the parent container?
2. How can I delete all rows? E.g. when looking up the sensors during run time all GroupBoxes are   dublicated, but everything should be created newly.
3. Layout of the question: how should I format terms like `TableLayoutPanel` correctly in this forum? It's my second question here and I haven't found out, yet.

For the second question. Currently I'm using this method that doesn't do what I'm expecting:

```
private void clearDashboardTable()
{
     if (sensorTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Count == sensorList.Count) {
          //MessageBox.Show(sensorTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Count.ToString());
          foreach (Control con in sensorTableLayoutPanel.Controls)
          {
               sensorTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(con);
               con.Dispose();
          }
          //sensorTableLayoutPanel.Dispose();
          sensorList.Clear();
     }
}
```

I commented out what I've tried so far in the above code or added additional comments. I used this topic to try to understand the basics of dynamic groupbox creation: [Add Row Dynamically in TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22420503/719186)

Comment: Third question seems to be answered (this time I was using Inline code for the terms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the outcome you describe is to make a custom `UserControl` containing a docked `GroupBox` that contains a docked `TableLayoutPanel`.

[image: user control designer]

To adjust the width when the container changes, attach to the `SizeChanged` event of the parent.

```
public partial class CustomGroupBox : UserControl
{
    public CustomGroupBox() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if((Parent != null) &&!DesignMode)
        {
            Parent.SizeChanged += onParentSizeChanged;
        }
    }
    private void onParentSizeChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{flowLayoutPanel.Width}");
            Width = 
                flowLayoutPanel.Width - 
                SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        }
    }
    public new string Text
    {
        get=>groupBox.Text;
        set=>groupBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

---

**Main Form**

The main form is laid out similar to your image except to substitute a `FlowLayoutPanel` on the right side.

[image: main form designer]

Now test it out with this minimal code in the method that loads the Main Form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    int _id = 0;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll= true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var customGroupBox = new CustomGroupBox
            {
                Text = $"Sensor {++_id}",
                Width = flowLayoutPanel.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth,
                Padding = new Padding(),
                Margin = new Padding(),
            };
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(customGroupBox);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: resizing]

---

**Clear**

An example of clearing the sensors would be to add a button and set a handler in the same Load method:

```
buttonClear.Click += (sender, e) => flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: I will check tomorrow and let you know. But thanks. Your answer looks good, but might need some changes in my real live example.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! If you would find it helpful, feel free to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/group-boxes-fill-parent-width.git) the code I used to test this answer from my GitHub repo.

Comment: Quick notice (2AM in Germany, almost going to bed ;-) - I was using Visual Studio 2019 and your code didn't work, my changes neither. I've updated now to Visual Code 2022 and can confirm that your code does what I want. I will look later today how I can change my code. Thanks a lot for the Git repository. Much more as what I have expected.

Comment: Thanks again. I redesigned my complete application, but now everything works, especially with the GroupBoxes - yes, I'm using another one in a different form. Working with custom user control was new for me, so thanks for this lesson as well. I will leave some credits once my project is finished - I will put it on Github, but there's a Youtube playlist about the project (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VK3Pj76e1gA&list=PLdIR8q_1oO5Du9xklO7tYyTcq_UK8M4-j), so I will add credits for your answer there in one of the next videos. Again: thanks a lot and take care ;-)